# cocoalibspotify: Crash when loading multiple playlists

Tags: ios, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I´m using cocoalibspotify(great stuff) for streaming Spotify music in my project.

After choosing a playlist this code runs:

```
 [[SPSession sharedSession] playlistForURL:myPlaylistUrl callback:^(SPPlaylist *playlist) {
    if(playlist != nil){

        _chosenPlaylist = playlist;
    }
}];
```

I later use `_chosenPlaylist` to create an array of all tracks. This works just fine for the first playlist I choose. However, when I choose another playlist (or the same one again) the block variable `playlist` is nil, which causes a crash.

Note: Before choosing the second playlist I dismiss the view controller so it should act the same way as it does the first time.

Any ideas on why playlist returns as nil the second time I run this code?

Edit: 
I´m using ARC.
The declaration for _chosenPlaylist looks like this  `SPPlaylist *_chosenPlaylist;`

The crash occurs because of this line:   `[playlists addObject:_chosenPlaylist];`, which makes sense since _chosenPlaylist is nil in this situation.

Comment: A bit more info please: Are you using ARC? How is _chosenPlaylist declared? The code you posted checks playlist for nil, so where is the crash actually occurring?

Comment: Hi @iKenndac, I´ve updated my post with some more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the only way that `playlistForURL:callback:` can return a `nil` playlist is if you're giving it an invalid URL. Double check your input (the value of `myPlaylistUrl`) - only URLs of the from `spotify:user:xxx:playlist:yyy` are accepted.